# How to pass the value of Json array into another array ? or how to Add a Json array into viewPager

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-viewpager

Can you help pls. thanks

I am getting a list of urls from the web using Json. I managed to get it into my **mJsonarray** now I need to pass it to my ViewPager which is getting the images from

```
String[] urls = {
    //"http://www.com/samples/1.png" NEED TO ADD the JSON ARRAY HERE ?
 };
```

Here is my code:

```js
public class GalleryUrlActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = GalleryUrlActivity.class.getSimpleName();  
    static String URL = " my url ";

    public static JSONObject mJsonobject;
    public static JSONArray mJsonarray;


    private GalleryViewPager mViewPager;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewer_main);


        getFlattenedData();

        //Intent i = getIntent();
        //img =  i.getStringExtra("img");

        //Log.v("Check the GalleryUrlActivity intent=== ", img); 



        String[] urls = {
                //"http://www.com/samples/1.png" SAMPLE
         }; 



        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.addAll(items, urls);  

        UrlPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new UrlPagerAdapter(this, items);
        pagerAdapter.setOnItemChangeListener(new OnItemChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemChange(int currentPosition)
            {
                Toast.makeText(GalleryUrlActivity.this, "Current item is " + currentPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mViewPager = (GalleryViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewer);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

       //getFlattenedData();



    }


//test **********************************************************

    public static  List<Composer> getFlattenedData() {
        //List<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

        //Log.e("urlItems = ", urlItems);

        //JSONObject jsonobject;
        //JSONArray jsonarray;

         List<Composer> res = new ArrayList<Composer>();


            //Add URL Encoding by sending post data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("c","getimages"));  
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1"));

            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            mJsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL2(URL, nameValuePairs);


            Log.v("GalleryUrlActivity @@@@@ ", mJsonobject.toString());

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                mJsonarray = mJsonobject.getJSONArray("data");

                Log.v("GalleryUrlActivity jsonarray !!!!!!!!! ", mJsonarray.toString());


                /*
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Composer s = new Composer(
                            jsonobject.getString("data"));

                    res.add(s);
                }*/
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         return res;
    }

//test ***********************************************************************************




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a String array at all? Why not cut out the middleman and pull all the url's from your JSON response into your List:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mJsonarray.length(); i++) {
    items.add(mJsonarray.getString(i));
}
```

Comment: ok, but still, how can add the items < ...items.add(mJsonarray > onto the List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();  --- I just tried to declare the items as a global <public static List<String> items;> still didn't work.
the UrlPagerAdapter expects a context and resource :  
public UrlPagerAdapter(Context context, List<String> resources)
 {
  super(context, resources);
 }

Comment: No problem. That's what this site is for. The code I supplied in my answer will populate your `List<String>` with the contents of `mJsonArray`. Simply replace `Collections.addAll(items, urls);` with the code block in the answer. =)